# how to show fixed hidden menu in a specific div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have developed a toggle menu, my code works perfectly without any problem. My menu is ideal to add on an adataptable website.

This is my complete code, fully functional:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
  var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();
  $('.capa').toggleClass('visible');  
  slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
});
});
```

```css
.slideout-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:-250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(15, 23, 27, 0.85);
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  z-index: 100;
}
.slideout-menu h3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #999;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.slideout-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #999;
}

.slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.capa {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.capa.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.slideout-menu.open {
  left: 0;
}

.bloque {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 600px;
 height: 100vh;
 background: bisque;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-menu-toggle">
  <div class="slideout-menu">
   <h3>Menu <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">&times;</a></h3>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="bloque">
  <div class="boton-menu-toggle">
   <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">Menu</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

But I would like to be able to make the menu appear and hide from a div specific.

Thus:

[image]

**And not in this way:**

[image]

can you explain how to get the hidden menu displayed and hidden in a specific div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to move your menu element inside the desired container (`.bloque`).

Then change the menu from `position:fixed` to `position:absolute`
and add `position:relative` to the container.

I also changed `left:-250px` to `left:-100vw` so that the menu goes completely off screen.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
    var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();
    $('.capa').toggleClass('visible');
    slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.slideout-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100vw;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(15, 23, 27, 0.85);
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  z-index: 100;
}

.slideout-menu h3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #999;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.slideout-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #999;
}

.slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.capa {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.capa.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.slideout-menu.open {
  left: 0;
}

.bloque {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: bisque;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bloque">

  <div class="container-menu-toggle">
    <div class="slideout-menu">
      <h3>Menu <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">&times;</a></h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="boton-menu-toggle">
    <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">Menu</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

If you want to hide that parts of the menu that appear outside of `.bloque`, you can use `overflow:hidden`. In that case, I'd set the menu to `left:-100%` rather than `left:100vw`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
    var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();
    $('.capa').toggleClass('visible');
    slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.slideout-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(15, 23, 27, 0.85);
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  z-index: 100;
}

.slideout-menu h3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #999;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.slideout-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #999;
}

.slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.capa {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.capa.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.slideout-menu.open {
  left: 0;
}

.bloque {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: bisque;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bloque">

  <div class="container-menu-toggle">
    <div class="slideout-menu">
      <h3>Menu <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">&times;</a></h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="boton-menu-toggle">
    <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">Menu</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean so that the menu does not show at all outside of the `.bloque` element? If so, you might try `overflow:hidden`...

Comment: excuse me. what he tried to tell him is that if there is no way to do it, in the same way, but that said menu appears in the specific div.

Comment: I edited my answer to address what I think you're aiming for.